# Swift 3 External Accessory Issues

Tags: swift, xcode, external, accessory

I'm essentially attempting to port parts of the EADemo (in Obj-C) that Apple provides for communication with an MFi device.  The demo works.  It recognizes when the MFi accessory is attached.  I have spent quite some time searching to determine my error, but I'm spinning my wheels.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleAccessoryAttach(_ :)), name: NSNotification.Name.EAAccessoryDidConnect, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleAccessoryDetach(_ :)), name: NSNotification.Name.EAAccessoryDidDisconnect, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleTestKey1), name: NSNotification.Name(testKey1), object: nil)


NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleTestKey2), name: NSNotification.Name(testKey2), object: nil)

EAAccessoryManager.shared().registerForLocalNotifications()

self.txt_rcvd.text = "Registered for local notifications"
```

The supported protocol is configured correctly in the plist (triple checked) and the other notifications fire when posted from button presses.  Below is my handler funcs.

```
func handleAccessoryAttach(_ notification:NSNotification){
    txt_rcvd.text = "Accessory Attached"
}


func handleAccessoryDetach(_ notification:NSNotification){
    txt_rcvd.text = "Accessory Detached"
}
```

Comment: Did you add the `<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key><array><string>com.example.apple-samplecode.data</string><string>com.yourcompany.serialtunnel.data</string></array>` to your plist?

Comment: What exactly is the problem or error you run into?

Comment: The problem was that the selector functions weren't being fired on connect/disconnect.  

I did add the protocol string to the plist.  I actually just created a new project and started over.  I copied most of the code from the non-working project and it worked.  I must have have simply overlooked something.  Either way, that part is working now.